# What could be an alternative for chlorophyll for cyanobacteria that use five micron infrared to make energy?

Tags: biology, creature-design, biochemistry, photosynthesis, bacteria

What would be a viable chlorophyll like protein be for a cyanobacterium that absorbs infrared light at the 5-20 micron range to produce energy in the form of ATP?

Comment: Apparently, some or maybe most [cyanobacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria) can use [chlorophyll-f](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_f) to capture the [energy of near-infrared light](https://www.laserfocusworld.com/lasers-sources/article/16571534/new-type-of-photosynthesis-uses-nearinfrared-rather-than-red-light). Unfortunately, ny acquaintance with the biochemistry of photosynthesis is nowhere near good enough to write a real answer. (And you don't really mean ATP, right? The direct output of photosynthesis is sugar, which is *then* used to make other useful stuff.)

Comment: Yeah, but what's a protein that can use 5-20 micron range infrared ?

Comment: @AlexP I assume OP is thinking of light-driven proton pumps that create gradient that can be used to make ATP.  Typically based on isomerization of retinol.

Answer (score 1):

There would probably not be a single protein to do that, but rather a complex of proteins and go-between energy storage solutions (gradients of some sort), as it is with the chlorophyll-driven [Photosystem](https://ttps://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/03/Thylakoid_membrane.svg/300px-Thylakoid_membrane.svg.png):

Your main problem is the miniscule energy content of single photons in these wavelengths: It decreases linearly with frequency, i.e double the wavelength, half the energy per photon. 620 nm carries about 2 eV with each photon, so 6micron carries only .2 eV...

To do something with the photonic energy, it is nice to be able to [break bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy) - sadly, you are out of range for that, even F-F , a pairing that practically begs for cleaving, will only be slightly perturbed by 6 micron infrared.

You would need to [jiggle some organic bonds](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Chem_002CH/Text/UNIT_IV%3A_MOLECULAR_SPECTROSCOPY/20.2%3A_Vibrations_and_Rotations_of_Molecules%3A_Infrared_and_Microwave_Spectroscopy), then translate that jiggling into something useful. This is ususally done by letting the impacts pile up on one large molecule or complex of molecules- while this is statistically worthwhile to hope for a second photon to impinge before the impact of the first has dissipated, hoping for ten of those impacts to happen basically simultaneously is not a good bet at all.

My guess would be that you would have to go and harvest the energy of the resulting heat (generalized jiggling) in some form, e.g. with [gates reactive to temperature](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2021/10/advanced-medicine-2021.pdf) - though that would mean the actual energy (i.e. some initial gradient) would need to come from somewhere else, the gates would then only, ahem, channel the energy.

Otherwise you could use the heat (which you would create by having a very absorptive melange of organic bonds for the right wavelengths) to physically (not via proteins) create the gradient which could then later be used to create ATP.

But it is an uphill battle, which is why the visible light strategies dominate.